# Geoprocessing tool output with name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

I am working on Geoprocessing tools and after completing it my tool output is provided as a shapefile with a tool name.

Could you please tell me how to provide the output file with a tool name?

[image]

Comment: I would try right-clicking on `Temp` and making it a Parameter first.  If you do that and it does not "just work" then can you **edit** your question to also provide pictures of the parameters set for your last two tools, please?

Comment: Actually my requirement is 2 polygons in my data one is building and another one is parcel in case building not in parcel or overlapping with parcel i need to provide error.i have set model parameter to temp folder that means output location i need output file with tool name.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is that you want to know how you can have your output shapefile name include the tool name. I think you can accomplish this by using a model only tool called Calculate Value. (Right click in the model builder window and select model only tools then calculate value.)

Here you can set the data type to string, and use a small python script to create the tool name you want to use. This value can then be used for inline string variable substitution.

I think if you combine this with the feature class to feature class tool instead of the feature class to shapefile tool, you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

The feature class to feature class tool can also convert from and to shapefile, not just feature class.

[image]

Comment: This would be a way of automating the naming convention. Of course if you did not mind manually entering the name each time you ran the tool, you could skip the calculate value tool and only use the feature class to feature class tool with the output as a parameter.